# How to write selenium webdriver automation script for Facebook logout?

Tags: facebook, selenium

I tried this code. Its automating the browser, logging in successfully but I'm not able to logout successfully. Please Help.

```
public class fb {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("https://facebook.com");

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='email']")).sendKeys("your email");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='pass']")).sendKeys("your password");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='u_0_n']")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='userNavigationLabel']")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.id("u_7_2")).click();// for logout-> button.But not working.
```

Comment: It goes to the drop down list,but doesn't click on the log out button successfully, despite giving the xpath of the log out button.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using the below code to click on the log out button

```
//wait for the userNavigationLabel to load fully any wait techniques implicit or explicit for sample i have used Thread.sleep although it is not recommended

Thread.sleep(3000);

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

String script = "var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) { if(forms[i].getAttribute('action')=='https://www.facebook.com/logout.php'){forms[i].submit();}}";

js.executeScript(script);
```

In the above code i have used javascript to click on the logout button...i tested it on the browser console it is working fine

Hope this helps you.....Kindly get back if you have any queries

Answer (score 0):

Automation Script for FaceBook Login and logout:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");

driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='email']")).sendKeys("your email");

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='pass']")).sendKeys("your password");

//click for login
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@id='loginbutton']/input")).click();

//Mouse over on logOut drop down menu icon,then click logout
WebElement mouseOverEle = driver.findElement(By.id("pageLoginAnchor"));

Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

actions.moveToElement(mouseOverEle).click().perform();

//click for logout
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Log Out']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    lsb=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pageLoginAnchor"]')
    lsb.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    mlb=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="u_d_3"]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[16]')
    time.sleep(2)
    mlb.click()
    inputElement33 = browser.find_element_by_name('pass').is_displayed()
    print("Looged out")
except:
    print("Cannot logout")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   // Enter you Email id
    dr.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='email']")).sendKeys("YorEmailID");
   // Enter you Password
    dr.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='pass']")).sendKeys("YourPassword");
    //click for login
    dr.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@id='loginbutton']/input")).click();
    dr.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    // Click for Alert
    dr.findElement(By.className("_3ixn")).click();
    //Click for Navigation Label
    dr.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='userNavigationLabel']")).click();
    dr.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //Click for Lout Button
    dr.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@data-gt,'menu_logout')]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your logout button click with this.

```
    //Wait for button appear
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4));
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//a[.='Log out']")));
    //Click it by xpath 
    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[.='Log out']")).Click();
```

Or:

```
    //Wait for button appear
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4));
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//a[.='Log out']")));
    //Click it by JS
    IJavaScriptExecutor js = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver);
    IWebElement logout = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[.='Log out']"));
    js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", logout);
```

100% worked

Answer (score 0):

```
**#Working script**
**#firefox can be used too instead of chrome**
**#sleep is necessary to give sufficient loading time**


from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from time import sleep

from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

usr=input('Enter Email Id:') 

pwd=input('Enter Password:') 

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/')

a = driver.find_element_by_id('email')

a.send_keys(usr)

b = driver.find_element_by_id('pass')

b.send_keys(pwd)

c = driver.find_element_by_id('loginbutton')

c.click()

sleep(20)

d= driver.find_element_by_id("userNavigationLabel")

d.click()

sleep(10)

e=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@data-gt,'menu_logout')]")

e.click()

sleep(5)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Some explanation would be useful.

Comment: Explanation regarding what? How selenium works or anything else? Be specific.

Answer (score 0):

There are duplicate objects in the Home page.Hence, to avoid confusion,Xpath can be written in combination of class names, which in our case is,

```
//div[@class='uiScrollableAreaBody']/following::div[@class='uiScrollableAreaContent']/following::ul/li
```

Get the maximum number of `<li>` tags in the `<ul>` as follows ,

```
List<WebElement> li = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='uiScrollableAreaBody']/following::div[@class='uiScrollableAreaContent']/following::ul/li"));

System.out.println("Size:"+li.size());
```

The Log out button will always be the last option, inspite of any changes to the list , hence append the last index to the xpath and click on it ,

```
String logOutBtn = "//div[@class='uiScrollableAreaBody']/following::div[@class='uiScrollableAreaContent']/following::ul/li[" + li.size() + "]";

driver.findElement(By.xpath(logOutBtn)).click(); -- Clicking on log out button
```

Hope this helps ! Thank you ..

Answer (score -1):

```java
package package1;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class class1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\CloudLogic.Tech01\\Desktop\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver drr = new ChromeDriver();
        drr.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
        drr.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("emailId"); 
        drr.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("********");
        drr.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@id='loginbutton']")).click();        
    }
}
```

Comment: please briefly explain what your code does and how it solves OPs issue